# Click on a specific part of an ImageView

Tags: imageview, zooming, imagebutton

I would like to be able to touch a specific part of an ImageView and display a toast.

Here is my xml file "dessintest.xml" :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/dessin1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then here is my main file "DessinTest.java" :

```
public class DessinTest extends Activity {

    ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dessintest);

        addListenerOnButton();

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dessin1);
        TouchImageView touch = new TouchImageView(this);
        touch.setImageBitmap(bm);
        touch.setMaxZoom(4f); //change the max level of zoom, default is 3f
        setContentView(touch);     

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

               Toast.makeText(DessinTest.this,"Click !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

When I try that, I can zoom the ImageView but I cannot see the ImageButton.
When I delete this bit of code (the one for the zooming of my ImageView) :

```
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dessin1);
        TouchImageView touch = new TouchImageView(this);
        touch.setImageBitmap(bm);
        touch.setMaxZoom(4f); //change the max level of zoom, default is 3f
        setContentView(touch);
```

it is working, I can see the ImageButton and click on it.

What I would like is to have both functionnalities, click and zoom.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I resolved my problem by using this sample :

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/sample/src/uk/co/senab/photoview/sample/SimpleSampleActivity.java

I can now zoom and touch/detect specific parts of the screen. It works very well !